# Retina display text rendering / making an application "Retina-ready"

Tags: xml, text, retina-display, freetype

I have a game that I really enjoy playing, "Football Manager 2012", which isn't optimised for retina and looks blurry/pixelly on the new MBPR screen. Its native resolution is 1280x800, but it can be changed up to 2560x1600, and although that makes the text crisp, it is tiny and you can barely read anything, as you would imagine.

I have tried every "hack" under the sun to make it Retina-compatible.
In the info.plist of the application, I added this line of code to make the app supposedly support Retina fonts (it's all I care about -- don't mind the graphics).

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key> <string>NSApplication</string> <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key> <true/>
```

I added that code to all three instances of the app (two in applications folders, one buried deep in the Steam directory). I even applied the code to the Steam application just in case that was the offender. I rebuilt the apps' plist cache using the copy-paste method for all of this. I ensured that the "open in low resolution" checkbox was unticked. Supposedly this would work -- no dice.

These tricks work with other applications, so why not this?

Then I tried an OS-wide line of code in Terminal to force apps to untick "open in low resolution". Still not working.

My next effort was trying to edit the xml settings of the Football Manager application itself. I found the xml file and where it has the font sizes. I downloaded all four OTF font files that are used in the game, so the computer 'possesses' a retina-capable font to utilise. There was also a line called "lcd_filter" and it was using "freetype" (obviously the type of text rendering). Nothing else in the xml seemed relevant apart from particular font sizes.

I'm not sure what more I can do.... it's really ticking me off. I know nothing has worked because the grey title bar of the application (in windowed mode) is still pixelated and has blurry traffic light buttons. Everything is still "non-retina".

Should I change the "freetype" in the xml to something else?

Can anyone help?

P.S. - Running a 13" Early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro with the latest OS (10.8.4)

Comment: It's possible that the app is using bitmap fonts, and not system provided vector based fonts.  If that is the case then nothing you can do will work.

Comment: @mjk I don't believe it's using bitmap fonts, as I found the four OTF fonts used in the game buried in a zipped settings file. The main font used is "Vera". I downloaded that (and the other three fonts) to my Mac's Font Book in the hope that that would help the app recognise the vector based fonts.

Perhaps it is to do with the "freetype" lcd filter? Some sort of rendering?

Comment: @mjk I've basically figured out that what I need to do. Say I wanted to make that 12-pt text "retina-ready". I need the application to render the font at 24-pt and then display it at half the size to make it crisp.

This is what the xml looks like, any ideas?

`<!-- default text settings -->
  <flags id="text_font" value="fonts/vera" />
  <integer id="text_style" value="plain" />
  <integer id="text_size_small" value="9"/>
  <integer id="text_size_normal" value="10" />
  <integer id="text_size_large" value="12" />`